# Get row with most minimum values in R

Tags: minimum

I have this problem that, for the life of me, I have been unable to solve. Some help would be highly appreciated.

Suppose we have this data.frame:

```r
Session <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A")
V1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4)
V2 <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3)
V3 <- c(3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2)
df <- data.frame(Session, V1, V2, V3)
df
  Session V1 V2 V3
1       A  1  1  3
2       B  1  1  1
3       C  2  2  2
4       A  3  1  3
5       B  2  1  2
6       A  4  3  2
```

I'd like to get the rows that have the **MOST** minimum values for each column **GROUPED** by the variable Session.

The expected ouput, in this case, would be the following:

```r
  Session V1 V2 V3
1       A  1  1  3
2       B  1  1  1
3       C  2  2  2
```

If more than one row has the same amount of minimum values per variable, one row should be valid enough.

Thank you very much,

Aleix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way of doing it, that I'm pretty sure is *not* the best way of doing. If you can improve this solution, please do.

First I created a data.table from the **df** object:

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(df)
```

Then I also created a function that returns the value of the most present element in a vector:

```r
most <- function(a1){ return(as.integer(names(sort(table(a1), decreasing = TRUE))[1]))}
```

To test it I executed the following:

```r
most(c(1,2,3,3,3,2,1))
[1] 3
```

Then I searched for the rows that contained the minimum values for each column:

```r
mins <- dt[, list(.I[which.min(V1)], .I[which.min(V2)], .I[which.min(V3)] ), by = "Session"]
mins
   Session V1 V2 V3
1:       A  1  1  6
2:       B  2  2  2
3:       C  3  3  3
```

And, finally, I used the previous result to search for those rows on the original data.table object (**dt**) like so:

```r
result <- dt[apply(mins[,, by=c("Session")], FUN = max_mins, MAR = 1)]
result
   Session V1 V2 V3
1:       A  1  1  3
2:       B  1  1  1
3:       C  2  2  2
```

That's about it. I really hope this can help someone.